# При импорте, запускается сама программа, без оболочки

Tags: python, python-3.x, импорт

Всем привет,Есть GUI оболочка и при нажатии на кнопку "Search", должна запускаться программа из другого файла(программа строит граф прохода по уязвимостям сети). При импорте, запускается сама программа, без оболочки.. Перечитала много форумов, но ответа толком не нашла.. С PyQt5 работаю в первый раз.. очень нужна ваша помощь

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication, QLineEdit, QDesktopWidget, QMessageBox, QToolTip, QPushButton,
                             QAction, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QFont
import run #это и есть та функция

class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.form_widget = FormWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.form_widget)

        exitAction = QAction(QIcon('exit.png'), '&Exit', self)
        exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit')
        exitAction.triggered.connect(self.closeEvent)
        self.statusBar()
        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)

        exitAction = QAction(QIcon('exit.png'), 'Exit', self)
        exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAction.triggered.connect(self.closeEvent)

        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('Exit')
        self.toolbar.addAction(exitAction)

        self.resize(500, 300)
        self.center()
        self.setWindowTitle('Spider')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('1.png'))
        self.show()

    def center(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Exit', "Are you sure to quit?", QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No,
                                     QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()


class FormWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(FormWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        QToolTip.setFont(QFont('SansSerif', 10))
        name = QLabel('Selected files:')
        file_vulnerability = QLabel('File vulnerability:')
        link_file = QLabel('Link file:')
        network_topology = QLabel('Network topology:')
        start_ip = QLabel('Start IP:')
        file_vulnerabilityEdit = QLineEdit()
        link_fileEdit = QLineEdit()
        network_topologyEdit = QLineEdit()
        start_ipEdit = QLineEdit()
        browse_1 = QPushButton("Browse", self)
        browse_2 = QPushButton("Browse", self)
        browse_3 = QPushButton("Browse", self)
        search = QPushButton("Search", self)
        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(10)
        grid.addWidget(name, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(file_vulnerability, 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(file_vulnerabilityEdit, 2, 1)
        grid.addWidget(browse_1, 2, 2)
        grid.addWidget(link_file, 3, 0)
        grid.addWidget(link_fileEdit, 3, 1)
        grid.addWidget(browse_2, 3, 2)
        grid.addWidget(network_topology, 4, 0)
        grid.addWidget(network_topologyEdit, 4, 1)
        grid.addWidget(browse_3, 4, 2)
        grid.addWidget(start_ip, 5, 0)
        grid.addWidget(start_ipEdit, 5, 1)
        grid.addWidget(search, 5, 2)

        self.setLayout(grid)
        self.show()

        search.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)

    def buttonClicked(self):
        run() 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    foo = MyMainWindow()
    foo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `run` это не функция, а модуль,который импортируется. В самом модуле есть код вне `if __name__ == '__main__':`, который и выполняется при импортировании, а так заголовок вопроса некорректен -- сигнал кнопки соединен с функцией `buttonClicked`, которая выполняется при клике

Comment: @gil9red не совсем поняла..

Comment: я про `import run`. `import <name>` импортирует модуль (файл .py). Почитайте больше об этом в питоне

Comment: @gil9red если я напишу вот так ничего не меняется from run import run

Comment: Я не знаю, что у вас в файле `run.py` находится, поэтому не могу сказать правильно ли вы делаете импорт. Замените `run()` в `buttonClicked` на `print("click")` и проверьте что после клика в консоли выводится, после можно разобраться что не так с `run` :)

Comment: @gil9red если в функции что-то принтовать, все работает, я добавила код импорта..

Comment: В конце `run.py` торчит `run()`. При импортировании вызывается весь код, что не входит в `if __name__ == '__main__':`, поэтому `run()` и вызывался, понятно?

Comment: @gil9red Ты чудо, спасибо большое)

Comment: В сторону: не обязательно `buttonClicked()` метод определять, который run() вызывает. Вы можете просто `run` функцию как есть передать в Питоне: `search.clicked.connect(run)`.